# react.js event handler is not returning updated data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react.js. I am following the video on youtube for learning react.js. I am working on simple event handling and stuck in some issue. I want to check/uncheck the checkbox when user performs onclick function on the checkbox. but somehow the returning array is not updated and checkbox is not actionable. I am pasting my code below:

### App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Todolist from './components/Todolist'
import todosData from './data/todosData'

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(id){
    this.setState(prevState => {
        console.log(prevState.todos)
        const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
          if(todo.id === id){
            todo.completed = !todo.completed
          }
          return todo
        })
        console.log(updatedTodos)
        return{
          todos : updatedTodos
        }
    })
  }

  render(){
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => <Todolist key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />)
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        {todoItems}
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

### TodoList.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Todolist(props){
    return(
        <div className='todo-item'>
            <input type='checkbox'
                   checked={props.item.completed} 
                   onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)} 
            />
            <span>{props.item.text}</span>
        </div>
        )
}

export default Todolist
```

Comment: Your `Todolist` component should actually be named `Todo` or `TodoItem`, since it represents a single Todo item. Improper naming impacts comprehension & may eventually lead to bugs.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of your console.

Comment: I replicated your code and it works perfectly fine. not sure what's wrong with yours: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zee3sl?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: It is strange that code is working at your end. may be environment difference or may be you are not using strict mode.

Comment: It is strange that code is working at your end. may be environment difference or may be you are not using strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mutate the original item/object of the array at this line!

```js
todo.completed = !todo.completed
```

You can try to create a new object using `Object.assign` or using spread. Both are fine but the spread way is preferable.

**Using `Object.assign`**

```js
  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map((todo) => {
        // Object.assign creates a new object!
        const changedTodo = Object.assign({}, todo, {
          completed: todo.id === id ? !todo.completed : todo.completed
        });

        return changedTodo;
      });
      return {
        todos: updatedTodos
      };
    });
  }
```

**Using spread `...`**

```js
handleChange(id) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map((todo) => {
        const changedTodo = {
          ...todo,
          completed: todo.id === id ? !todo.completed : todo.completed
        };

        return changedTodo;
      });
      return {
        todos: updatedTodos
      };
    });
  }
```

Comment: Awesome reply, it works brother. But I have one confusion here. do not we mutating the original object inside return on below line?

todos: updatedTodos

here we are completely updating original object. isn't it the mutation?

Comment: When you return from `setState` that's being handled by React. We don't need to pass the other properties with the return object. And `state` is mutable and `props` is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856#issuecomment-390206425), `setState` runs twice in [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). The state updater function gets called twice with the same input. Which should be fine and produce the same output. But the problem here is you have reused the `todo` object instead of creating a new one. Which in turn causes the `completed` flag to be flipped twice.

You can change your updater function to create a new todo object every time:

```js
this.setState(prevState => {
  const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
    if (todo.id === id) {
      return {
        ...todo,
        completed: !todo.completed,
      };
    }
    return todo;
  });
  return {
    todos: updatedTodos,
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply brother. It works perfectly. But I have one confusion here. do not we mutating the original object inside return on below line? todos: updatedTodos here we are completely updating original object. isn't it the mutation?